# Janet Kagan: "Uhura's Song" sequels

Tags: star-trek

The Star Trek novel [Uhura's Song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uhura%27s_Song) is a personal favorite of mine. Apparently, author [Janet Kagan](http://www.janetkagan.com/) (who died in 2008) had written sequels, which were not published due to a policy not allowing an author's original characters making a re-appearance.

Is there *any* chance of getting my hands on these sequels?

Comment: On the webpage you've linked, there's an email address for the site administrator promising some unpublished works. Have you emailed it? http://www.janetkagan.com/

Comment: @Richard: I am pretty sure I did so a couple of years ago, without reply IIRC. However, when I tried it again, I got this reply: *"There were two sequels planned, but not written. The editor, at the time, was interested, but word from on high nixed it. -- Ricky"*.

Comment: That ties in very nicely with the interview below. Case closed.

Comment: "not published due to a policy not allowing an author's original characters making a re-appearance." - what policy? It all depends on the contract she made with the publisher / CBS / Paramount I would think. There are characters from various authors littering the entire scope of Trek lit.

Comment: @NKCampbell: Look at Valorum's answer, which quotes the author directly. It seems this was a general policy at least at the time Kagan was writing the novel and considering the sequels. That policy might have changed in the meantime; I am not that familiar with the rest of the ST novels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is no. Based on this interview in [Star Trek: Voyages of Imagination: The Star Trek Fiction Companion](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=avZlUJBIJDMC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=%22Uhura%27s%20Song%22%20and%20sequels&source=bl&ots=wIISdfgoWt&sig=US7iJziysl9bN104a4qarVRrPes&hl=en&sa=X&ei=r_3RVIyfN9f1atjOgsgI&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22Uhura's%20Song%22%20and%20sequels&f=false), it looks like the sequels never got past the planning stage

> **Will Janet write a sequel to Uhura's Song?** *"I had so much fun writing the second draft that, between paragraphs, I sketched out not
>   one but two sequels. Both of them had the same guest star: Evan Wilson
>   /Tail-Kinker/my mom. When a new editor took over the Trek series, I
>   thought perhaps things had gone back to normal in the editorial
>   offices, so I submitted my outline for the second. To make a long
>   story short, the next two Trek editors in a row wanted me to write it
>   for them but (by then the policy was] that Trek novelists weren't
>   allowed to bring back their own characters. So, no, there won't be any
>   sequels: Star Trek just wouldn't be as much fun for me without
>   Tail-Kinker."*

I would imagine that the "*unpublished works*" promised on her website would be incomplete notes and individual chapters rather than whole books.

Comment: A very good find -- because knowing that the sequels never went beyond the "sketch" stage is an acceptable second-best to *reading* them. (The idea of Evan Wilson fiction remaining *unread* was somewhat depressing.)

Comment: @DevSolar - Authors don't tend to leave behind entire books.

Comment: @DevSolar - Also, this interview only pre-dated her death by 18 months. Given her illness, it seems unlikely she'd have had time to write one, let alone two books.